# How to override ArrayField default error messages in template?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to change the default error message Django generates for ArrayField (Specifically too many items entered error message)

If a user enters too many items to my ArrayField the following message generates in the template:

> List contains 4 items, it should contain no more than 3.

I want to change this message to

> You can't have more than 3 topics.

I have tried adding the following error_messages to my forms.py TopicForm Meta class but had no success

```
    error_messages = {
        'topic': {
            'invalid': ("You can't have more than 3 topics."),
        },
```

Here is my models.py file

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model)
    topic = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20), size=3, blank=True,    null=True)
```

and my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic

        fields = ['topic']
```

Would apperciate some input on this! Thank you!

Comment: So does it keep displaying `List contains 4 items, it should contain no more than 3.` even with the custom error message?

Comment: Yes I added the custom error message under the class Meta and it still displays the default error message

Comment: Very strange. And if you try to add a custom error message for a different kind of model field, say `CharField`, does that work?

Comment: When I add the custom error message for other fields it works normally. The ArrayField appears to have different error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayField` has multiple error 'codes' to deal with various types of user inputs.

The error 'code' for an array which is overpopulated with elements is `max_length`.

Here is the rewritten code with the piece you were missing :)

```
error_messages = {
    'topic': {
        'max_length': ("You can't have more than 3 topics."),
     },
```

By the way you may also want to customize your `item_invalid` error message for when users try to submit incomplete inputs.

For example an attempt to submit `string1,string2,` (See the extra comma?)
will raise:

> Item 3 in the array did not validate

You can customize the `item_invalid` message by adding:

```
error_messages = {
        'topic': {
            'max_length': ("You can't have more than 3 topics."),
            'item_invalid': ("Your customized message"),
         },
```